# AngularJS report backend errors

Tags: angularjs

Managed to rewrite my project with AngularJS except for reasonable backend error handling.

I only wish for a generic way to catch Ajax error response and modify the scope accordingly.

In JQuery, I would do the following :

1. Set an element (lets call it ajaxRoot) on Ajax settings
2. I'd make sure the backend sends error on header "display-messages" where each key matches a name for element under ajaxRoot. for example

   ```
   <div id="myAjaxSection">
       <span class="view-port">
             <input name="username"/>
       </span>
   </div>

   $.ajax({
       ajaxRoot : $("#myAjaxSection"), 
       ... 
    });
   ```
3. use `ajaxError` for catching all ajax errors, looks something like

   ```
   if ( ajaxSettings.ajaxRoot && jqXHR.getResponseHeader("display-messages")){
       var msgs = JSON.parse( jqXHR.getResponseHeader("display-message"));
       var $ajaxRoot = ajaxSettings.ajaxRoot;
       var k;
       for ( k in msgs ){
           $ajaxRoot.find("[name=" + k + "]" ).closest(".view-port" ).addClass("error").popover({content: msgs[k]});
       }
   }
   ```

This would easily take care of all errors on any page assuming the conventions I decided on.

Now I am trying to reach something similar with AngularJS. Here is what I have tried so far

1. http interceptors - but I cannot access the scope.
2. http interceptors + publish/subscribe to event - would require code duplication in each controller.
3. error handlers on $http calls - causes code duplications again.

Currently I am stuck. 
I need guidance on how to proceed?

## EDIT

I hate answering my own questions.

I have an ugly, yet reasonable, solution for now. Would appreciate more answers on this topic.

Answer (score 2):

My ugly yet reasonable solution for now is as follows :

Even though the interceptors cannot access "$scope" - they can access "$rootScope".

***note*** - when I debugged the interceptor and tried to evaluate "$rootScope" I got a "no such reference" error.. which is weird. Once I used "console.log" to print it, it worked well.

under my app configuration I would do

```
$httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push('myInterceptor');
```

And then I define my interceptor as follows

```
MyApp.factory( 'myInterceptor', function ( $rootScope, $q, $window )
{
    function success( response )
    {
        $rootScope.formErrors = {};
        return response;
    }

    function error( response )
    {
        var status = response.status;
        if ( status == 401 ) {
            window.location = "/";
            return;
        }

        var hdrs = response.headers();
        if ( hdrs["display-message"]){
            var displayMessages = JSON.parse(hdrs["display-message"]);
            if ( displayMessages["formErrors"]){
                $rootScope.formErrors = displayMessages["formErrors"];
            }
        }
        console.log(["hdrs",hdrs]);
        // otherwise
        return $q.reject( response );
    }

    return function ( promise )
    {
        return promise.then( success, error );
    };
} );
```

Now all that it is left is to reference rootScope.formErrors from the template like so

```
<div id="myAjaxSection">
    <span class="view-port" ng-class="{'error':formErrors['username'] != null}">
          <input name="username"/>
    </span>
</div>
```

Which - thank got to templates is doable without too much code repetition.

```
<div id="myAjaxSection">
    <span class="view-port" ng-class="{'error':formErrors['@name'] != null}">
          <input name="@name"/>
    </span>
</div>
```

All that is left now is to resolve how to implement the "popover" - I am sure something exists somewhere.

I hate this solution.. doesn't feel right.. if anyone has anything better to suggest - please do.